# rxjs: scan accumulator mutation

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I was (wrongly) under the impression that the scan operator would always return a new object on each pass. I've discovered recently that is not the case.

I've forked the example from [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) to demonstrate what I mean [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vwlv96?file=index.ts).

Taking a look at the code:

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();

const example = subject.scan((acc, curr) => {
    console.log('Accumulator', acc);
    return Object.assign({}, acc, curr)
}, {});

//log accumulated values
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => {
    val.mutating = 'test'
    console.log('Accumulated object:', val)
});

//next values into subject, adding properties to object
subject.next({name: 'Joe'}); 
// {name: 'Joe'}

subject.next({age: 30}); 
// {name: 'Joe', age: 30}

subject.next({favoriteLanguage: 'JavaScript'}); 
// {name: 'Joe', age: 30, favoriteLanguage: 'JavaScript'}
```

I am mutating the `val` passed down the stream in the `subscription` and logging out the value of the `accumulator` in the `scan` accumulator function.

Looking at the console, it shows that the accumulator contains `mutating:"test"` after the first and subsequent passes:

[image]

Unless I am mistaken this demonstrates that I can mutate stream objects anywhere down the line up to and in the subscription. Which, I suppose does not surprise me as it is an object reference. But, I thought that the `scan` operator would always return a new object preventing its internal accumulator to be mutated...

First thought I have is mapping a new object like this:

```
scan((acc, curr) => Object.assign({}, acc, curr), {}),
map(data=>Object.assign({}, data))
```

But that seems odd to me.

Is the behaviour I am demonstrating expected or am I not understanding how this all works? How can I prevent the accumulator from being mutated?

Thank-you

Comment: You're carefully copying in everything from `curr`, so why is it surprising that the mutation persists? Yes you're building a new object, but *with all of the old properties*.

Comment: I thought that the scan operator would return a new object each time it reduced

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a object reference -> `acc` that you are changing. You can freeze the Object like below to stop it from mutating.

```
 return Object.freeze(Object.assign({},acc, curr));
```